# Favourites option disabled in GNOME Maps

Tags: gnome, 17.10, 18.04

I like OpenStreetMaps as it very nice alternative to maps.google and is supported on many platforms.

However I would like to save favourites and the button in top right corner is grayed out.

EDIT: **What's here** after right clicking on the map returns *Nothing found here!*

[image]

According to [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/introduction-gnome-maps) it should work. Do you have any idea where's the problem?

The version of GNOME Maps I am using is 3.26.1.

Comment: The star button in top right is for *(already) starred locations*. Start starring some places, that button will be activated.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- right-clicking on a map location
- choosing What's here?
- clicking the star icon to add it to favourites

Comment: Thank you, but **What's here** button always returns the *Nothing found here!*. Even after update to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: are you testing this while connected to the internet? also can you share location(s) you tried this with?

Answer (score 0):

Try the flatpak version of gnome-maps: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Maps

It has worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 x64: favorites are back and search function works as expected.

**1. Install Flatpak**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

**2. Install the Software Flatpak plugin**

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```

**3. Add the Flathub repository**

```
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

**4. Restart (if necessary)**

**5. Install Gnome-Maps via Gnome-Software or via the command line**

```
sudo flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Maps
```

**6. Run the app**

```
flatpak run org.gnome.Maps
```